# pass dynamic value in xml attribute in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xml, xml-parsing

I worked with an API that accepts XML as a request body. How can I add dynamic value as a string in the XML attribute?

My request body should be like this.

```
const req= `<text category = "message">Hello Geeks</text>`
```

But the `category` value will be dynamic. I tried this,

```
const req= <text category = ${message}>Hello Geeks</text>
```

In that way, my payload will be,

```
// assume the message value is abc
<text category = abc>Hello Geeks</text>
```

But I need this,

```
<text category = "abc">Hello Geeks</text>
```

Note: I want to implement it in a React.js project

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. I share my solution, maybe it helps someone.

we can do this like this,

```
const req= `<text category = "${message}">Hello Geeks</text>`
```

or

```
const req= <text category = `"${message}"`>Hello Geeks</text>
```

In this way, the payload will be

```
// assume the message value is abc
<text category = "abc">Hello Geeks</text>
```